How to debug Godot web builds are too big?
My Godot web build is too big for itch.io's web build requirements. In fact, the index.pck in the exported build is bigger than my entire project:
$ du -sh --exclude=.git --exclude=.godot jumpgame builds/jumpgame/web/index.pck
33M     jumpgame
331M    builds/jumpgame/web/index.pck

How can I debug what files are making the build so large?

Have you tried any of the official Godot recommendations for optimizing a build for size?

@Pikalek: Those appear to be for optimizing godot.exe editor for size, not an exported build. The breadcrumbs are "Engine development > Building from source > Optimizing a build for size"

Most of it is, but there's a section specifically about optimizing the distribution of your project and it mentions web export in particular. I edited my link to point to that area of the docs - sorry for the initially confusing link.

Looks like Godot doesn't natively support brotli packing your pck. Seems like you could compress it, rename to index.pck.br after export, and modify the export template to look for that new file, but I'm not sure how to do that last step.

Export project as a zip so you can unpack and inspect file sizes.

Project > Export, select web, click "Export PCK/ZIP..." button.
Save file as index.zip to create a zip file that you can open.
Unpack the resulting index.zip.
Use WinDirStat, Baobab, or other disk usage analyzer to find large files in the unpacked folder.

(It's normal to have a .godot folder -- that's where your baked assets are stored.)

For me, there were a bunch of textures that are 1.33 MB as pngs but 234 MB in the exported project:

Changing their import settings from "VRAM Compressed" to "Lossy" and disabling mipmaps reduced my index.pck to 195 MB. (It's a single static background scene so I'd never use the mips and it only loads once.) After more digging, I realized these images were duplicated in the project (hence two ST_CanyonBG_0.png-blahblah). After updating references and removing the copies, my index.pck is only 89 MB!
